# Equivalent of Tablesample for MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table Acess doesn't support Tablesample and I just want to get 100 random rows from a query how do I do it.

Here is the original query that will not work in MS-Access.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Central Shipto Query] TABLESAMPLE (100 Rows) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty random SELECT using Access, you can `ORDER BY RND(your_column)` and `SELECT TOP n` rows. Make sure that your_column is an integer and is unique-ish per row.